zigbee2mqtt fails to start with symlinked port name
I have installed zigbee2mqtt on my AlmaLinux 9 host. When I start zigbee2mqtt it fails with error:

Inappropriate ioctl for device setting custom baud rate of 115200

Relevant info below:
 npm start

> zigbee2mqtt@1.40.1 start
> node index.js

Starting Zigbee2MQTT without watchdog.
[2024-09-08 17:47:34] info:     z2m: Logging to console, file (filename: log.log)
[2024-09-08 17:47:34] info:     z2m: Starting Zigbee2MQTT version 1.40.1 (commit #403d3c09)
[2024-09-08 17:47:34] info:     z2m: Starting zigbee-herdsman (0.57.3)
[2024-09-08 17:47:37] info:     zh:zstack:znp: Opening SerialPort with {"path":"/dev/ttyZigbee","baudRate":115200,"rtscts":false,"autoOpen":false}
[2024-09-08 17:47:37] error:    z2m: Error while starting zigbee-herdsman
[2024-09-08 17:47:37] error:    z2m: Failed to start zigbee
[2024-09-08 17:47:37] error:    z2m: Check https://www.zigbee2mqtt.io/guide/installation/20_zigbee2mqtt-fails-to-start.html for possible solutions
[2024-09-08 17:47:37] error:    z2m: Exiting...
[2024-09-08 17:47:37] error:    z2m: Error: Error: Inappropriate ioctl for device setting custom baud rate of 115200
[root@lserver zigbee2mqtt]# ls -ls /dev/ttyZigbee
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Sep  8 17:39 /dev/ttyZigbee -> bus/usb/002/005
[root@lserver zigbee2mqtt]# cat data/configuration.yaml
homeassistant: false
permit_join: true
mqtt:
  base_topic: zigbee2mqtt
  server: mqtt://localhost
serial:
  port: /dev/ttyZigbee
advanced:
  network_key:
    - 68
    - 199
    - 70
    - 194
    - 14
    - 219
    - 49
    - 30
    - 68
    - 42
    - 156
    - 79
    - 207
    - 92
    - 106
    - 1
  pan_id: 53725
  ext_pan_id:
    - 32
    - 43
    - 171
    - 12
    - 159
    - 222
    - 166
    - 211

I am NOT using a container.  If I cat /dev/ttyZigbee I see output, and I confirmed it is symlinked to the right device (/dev/ttyACM1).  If I modify my configuration.yaml to use port /dev/ttyACM1 instead, I see:
[2024-09-08 18:00:54] info:     z2m: Logging to console, file (filename: log.log)
[2024-09-08 18:00:54] info:     z2m: Starting Zigbee2MQTT version 1.40.1 (commit #403d3c09)
[2024-09-08 18:00:54] info:     z2m: Starting zigbee-herdsman (0.57.3)
[2024-09-08 18:00:58] warning:  zh:ezsp: Deprecated driver 'ezsp' currently in use, 'ember' will become the officially supported EmberZNet driver in next release. If using Zigbee2MQTT see https://github.com/Koenkk/zigbee2mqtt/discussions/21462
[2024-09-08 18:01:02] info:     zh:ezsp:driv: Leaving current network and forming new network
[2024-09-08 18:01:03] info:     zh:ezsp:driv: Form network
[2024-09-08 18:01:07] error:    zh:ezsp:uart: --> Error: Error: {"sequence":0} after 4000ms
[2024-09-08 18:01:07] error:    zh:ezsp:uart: -!- break waiting (0)
[2024-09-08 18:01:07] error:    zh:ezsp:uart: Can't send DATA frame (7,2,0): 1f0001ab00070001
[2024-09-08 18:01:09] info:     zh:controller: Wrote coordinator backup to '/usr/local/zigbee2mqtt/data/coordinator_backup.json'
[2024-09-08 18:01:09] info:     z2m: zigbee-herdsman started (reset)
[2024-09-08 18:01:09] info:     z2m: Coordinator firmware version: '{"meta":{"maintrel":"3 ","majorrel":"6","minorrel":"10","product":8,"revision":"6.10.3.0 build 297"},"type":"EZSP v8"}'

So, why won't this program start with the symlink (but will with the /dev/ttyACM1 name).  Since the order of ttyACM* devices changes on bootup, I should not use the ACMx name.
My udev rule is pretty straight forward (but maybe I messed something up):
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idProduct}=="55d4", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1a86", SYMLINK+="ttyZigbee"


No idea about why you can’t use a symlink but maybe once you check the source code you’ll see a check if the provided “file name “ is the proper device type and a symlink is not

@HBruijn: Could you tell me what the expected (acceptable) symlink file name format is? (Save me from studying the source code)? Thanks
